# Sorting with Perl respecting Locale Settings

Tags: perl, sort, locale

Following data needs to be sorted respecting the locale sort order:

```
wird
sin
wär
pêche
war
Über
Uber
péché
peach
```

There was nor problem by using `sort`

```
$ sort < data
peach
pêche
péché
sin
Uber
Über
war
wär
wird
```

which respects the locale, and

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort < data
Uber
peach
péché
pêche
sin
war
wird
wär
Über
```

without locale.

Now I tried to do so with `perl`, but I'm failed:

```
$ perl -e 'local $/ = undef; print sort <>;' < data
Über
pêche
war
péché
sin
Uber
peach
wär
wird
```

The result is either the first output of sort, nor the second.

Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: What does `perl -e 'use locale; local $/ = undef; print sort <>;' < data` tell you?

Comment: no changes, like the last output. default locale is `en_US.UTF-8` but it should work because `sort` without any settings works too and the data is in `utf8`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `local $/ = undef`. It causes `perl` to read entire file in to `@ARGV` array, meaning it contains only one element, so `sort` can not sort it (because you are sorting an array with only one element). I expect the output must be the same with your beginning data (I also use `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, perl version 5.14.2`:

```
$ perl -le 'local $/ = undef;print ++$i for <>' < cat
1

$ perl -le 'print ++$i for <>' < cat
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

If you remove `local $/ = undef`, perl `sort` will proceduce same output with the shell `sort with LC_ALL=C`:

```
$ perl -e 'print sort <>' < data
Uber
peach
péché
pêche
sin
war
wird
wär
Über
```

**Note**

Without `use locale`, `perl` ignores your current locale settings. Perl comparison operators `("lt", "le", "cmp", "ge", and "gt")` use `LC_COLLATE` (when `LC_ALL` absented), and `sort` is also effected because it use `cmp` by default.

You can get current `LC_COLLATE` value:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX=setlocale -le 'print setlocale(LC_COLLATE)'
en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: @Ouki posted the right answer one minute earlier. To be fair you've got +1 because your answer is also correct.

Comment: I think my answer is one minute earlier. Don't mind!

Comment: lol, ok, so you'll be happier. :-)

Comment: Don't mind! I only want to know you have a reason about technique causes you don't accept my answer. Now I know there is no reason:)

Answer (score 6):

Because the correct way to read a file into an array is:

```
$ perl -e 'print sort <>;' < data
```

Setting the *input record separator* to undef is only putting your whole file into a single scalar. Then sorting a single value array does not mean much.

Array mode is already reading your whole file in one shot. Then sorting would be meaningful:

```
$ perl -e 'use locale; print sort <>;' < data
peach
péché
pêche
sin
Uber
Über
war
wär
wird
```

Here, my `ENVIRONMENT` has `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. Without the `use locale;` statement you would use the default `LC_ALL=C` sorting scheme.

If you want to know more:

- [Traditional slurping with Perl](http://www.sysarch.com/Perl/slurp_article.html#traditional%20slurping)
- [Perl "use locale" and environment](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#ENVIRONMENT)